# Innovation in heat-sink design?

Tags: heat, heatsink

20 years ago, if you opened up a consumer-level desktop computer its heatsink would be a "metal grill" type device place on top of the CPU.

20 years later, if you open up a consumer-level desktop computer, its heatsink will most likely still be a "metal grill" (albeit smaller) type device on top of the CPU.

How come with millions being spent on microproecssor R+D, trying to reduce heat emissions, heatsink design seems not to have experienced any radical innovation. For a component which plays such a crucial role, I am surprised by this. Can anyone help explain it?

Comment: Nobody has repealed either Newton's law of cooling (1701) or Stefan-Boltzmann's law (1879) for radiation. So, moving heat around hasn't changed much. There are heatpipes and water cooling systems but plumbing is still messy and expensive. Liquid sodium/potassium eutectics are still somewhat dangerous. Peltier is still hopelessly inefficient for most applications. So what do you expect to change?

Comment: I disagree with your "albeit smaller". Consumer PC heatsinks are *massive* compared to what they were 20 years ago, because CPUs produce way more heat than they used to. Back in the 90s, some CPUs didn't need a heatsink at all!

Comment: Very interesting historical perspective @Hearth. So, when did CPUs and heat start to become a problem?

Comment: @Hearth a few didn't but the reality is that plenty of late 90's machines had _huge_ heatsinks and there are plenty of modern machines which leverage increased thermal efficiency to produce less heat while doing more work.  It's just if you use modern CPUs to do *drastically* more work that even with efficiency gains they need larger heatsinks.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Sure, late 90s and high-end machines, but I don't think early 90s and especially late 80s PCs had much in the way of heatsinks. I remember seeing a 486 once that had to specifically say on the packaging that a heatsink was required, because that wasn't something people would just assume to be a requirement at the time. And even then the heatsink was small. (I think this was something sold as an upgrade for low-end PCs of the time, though)

Comment: @ChrisStratton None PC I saw, using processors up through the 80486DX, used heat sinks. The max clock rate was modest back then. I think the fastest 80486DX I ever saw was 66 MHz. But maybe it was 50 MHz. My memory is unclear on that. We didn't start seeing 100 MHz or better until the Pentium rolled out. And even then we didn't use much by way of heat sinks. Neither CPU running on my dual PPro board, running at 150 MHz, used a heat sink (mid 90's.) We could, but it was okay without. That was around the time heat sinks became an issue -- most especially starting with the P II.

Comment: @daikin There are three ways to remove heat: convection, conduction, and radiation. The physics hasn't changed at least since humans had any practical theory regarding heat, temperature, and entropy. Which goes back more than a century. Neither the ambient temperature of the planet, nor its atmosphere, have altered significantly and few new elements have been discovered since. But there is a chance now, with the advent of 3D metal printing, to construct novel heat sink designs. So who knows? You may see something sooner than later that couldn't be made before coming from that angle.

Comment: @daikin Never mind. I just googled it. Apparently, folks are already using 3D metal printing for making more efficient heat sinks!! I should have earlier guessed that it was already done and not something set to happen in the future.

Comment: @jonk, thanks for that informative answer. I just find it bizarre. Millions of dollars are being poured into microprocessor design to make them cooler but externally we're still left with relatively crude heatpipes and heatsinks from the 1970s. Now going to check out some 3D printed heatsinks...Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has been substantial innovation in CPU cooler design, and indirectly, heatsink design.  Your reasoning as to why there isn't seems to be 'heatsinks superficially still look like heatsinks, therefore they have not advanced' which doesn't really make much sense.

Drawing from your question, CPUs from 20 years ago look essentially the same as ones from 2020.  They're a die on an interposer that fits into a socket on the motherboard.  The only noticeable difference is most CPUs made in the year 2000 lacked heat spreaders (the large metal shield roughly the size of the interposer that hides the CPU die, and is thermally coupled to it), while all CPUs today have heat spreaders.  The visual differences between CPU coolers in 2000 and 2020 is frankly much more significant than that of CPUs, so if that means heatsinks haven't seen any innovation, that must mean neither have CPUs in the last 20 years, right?

Here is the Athlon Thunderbird, which was released in 2000.  [image]

See?  Visually, little has changed.  In fact, one might even assume that the 2000 CPU is the more recent one, given that it uses a more robust ceramic substrate.

But the thunderbird had 37 million transistors.  But a current generation Threadripper from AMD has **39 billion** transistors.  That is over a 1,052 fold increase, or slightly better than a Moore's law type doubling of transistors every 2 years for 20 straight years (which would be a 1024 fold increase).

I'm trying to make the point of how useless the metric you are applying here is.

Of course heatsinks still look like heatsinks, that's just what they look like.  They will always look like that because surface area is how one dissipates heat.

#### Innovate what?

Like most innovations, innovation in CPU coolers and heatsinks in general have primarily been driven by need rather than innovation for innovation's sake.  It is important to keep in mind that it wasn't until the last 15 years or so that CPUs even generated enough heat to ***require*** any real innovation in heatsinks.  Using the AMD Thunderbird as an example, a real 'hotrod' of a CPU back in 2000, had a TDP of 50W.  This is on par with high-end laptop/mobile CPUs today (45W).  Other cpus of the era, and of course older ones had much lower dissipations, in the teens or 20s of watts.  They didn't produce enough heat to require active cooling at all - just a passive aluminum heatsink was more than enough to cool any CPU back then.

Also, the "millions spent of R&D" to reduce CPU power dissipation was not done for thermal reasons.  We are not limited by our ability to remove heat from something with the power density of even enterprise class (205W+), not even close.  Modern GPUs with TDPs of over 375W are widely available, but workstation GPUs from a few generations ago could have yet higher TDPs.  The NVIDIA Tesla S2050, released in 2011, had a TDP of ***900W*** for example.  That is from a single silicon die.

So clearly we've had the capability to cool much higher TDPs for a while, thus removing any need to optimize CPU heat dissipation - at least, if that was really the reason.

It wasn't, and isn't.  The reasons are about energy usage, not heat. At least, not about heat in the context of immediately cooling the CPU (more on that shortly).  TDP is also a measure of the power or rate of energy usage of a CPU, and all the efforts to reduce TDP have been to make computers do more with fewer watts.

I think you need to understand the shear scales that are at play here.  In 2017, **data centers alone consumed on average *416 Terawatts***.  This is ***3% of all electricity generated by the entire human race.***  The number has only grown in the years since, and will continue to do so.  This does not even include the vast number of client computers and devices used by individuals by the billions.  This is anything but trivial.  And any hardware that can do more with the same energy consumption, or even better, saves even just a single watt, will have a huge impact globally as the technology gets adopted.

Data centers primary expense is electricity, not the hardware itself.  Even modest improvements in energy usage make replacing large swaths of equipment economically favorable.  Beyond that, reductions in waste heat being exhausted into a data center server room means that much less air conditioning and the power it uses is needed to cool that room.  Of course, the trend recently has been favoring increased performance, or doing more with the same amount of power, rather than actually reducing the per-processor TDP.  And thanks to that R&D you mentioned, now there is very little wasted energy for capacity that isn't being used.  A 28 core 205W Xeon, when idle, can use 10W total.  As there is very little disadvantage to having capacity that isn't necessarily always being completely used, there has been little incentive to actually lower TDP, but rather do more with the same TDP.

My point is that modern heatsinks are adequate for our needs, always have been, and have ***plenty*** of headroom to cool much higher TDPs than are typically seen today.  The R&D poured into keeping CPU TDPs lower has almost nothing to do with heatsinks, they are not a bottleneck here, so why would we bother to innovate something that needs no innovation?

Really, it is unclear what exactly you even mean by 'innovation'.  What exactly are you even imagining would be innovated upon?  What are these fictional future heatsinks supposed to even be?  What metric makes them 'better'?

We can't get around thermodynamics.  Fundamentally, anything (heatsink or otherwise) can dissipate heat by 3 methods:  radiation (this is why really hot things glow, and why even your own body is glowing, albeit in normally invisible infrared light), conduction (something hot in contact with something not will see heat flow from the hot thing into the not thing), and convection (doesn't work in a vacuum, this is really just conduction but into the air, which causes the air to move).

And all of these methods have one thing in common: they are totally dependent on surface area.  No matter how you try, the rate at which you can dump heat is ultimately going to scale to how much surface area of hot stuff you have to dump it.  For that reason, heatsinks will always look like, well, heatsinks.  As in, they will optimize for surface area.  This is a fundamental requirement for dissipating heat, and furthermore, at least on Earth, the best way to do this is via convection.  Every cooling system is ultimately convective.  Liquid coolers still have a radiator, which is cooled by convection.  If you want to move heat out of something into the wider environment, then it will ultimately be by convection, no matter how long the chain is to get there.  This means that we also need to optimize for air flow over all that surface area, and beyond some cleverness verified with fluid dynamic simulations, there is nothing there to innovate.  There is an optimal maximum where increasing surface area (in a fixed heatsink volume) will start to hinder air flow, requiring higher static pressure to push air through the fins.  There is no way around this.  Which is why GPU coolers are typically so much louder - because they have to be to fit their cooling solution in the space allowed by the PCIE card spec.  They are at the maximum where increasing surface area reduces airflow enough that even using a more powerful fan would cool better if one simply reduced the surface area in favor of having that much more airflow, vs increasing the surface area slightly but at the cost of less airflow.

It is a trade off, one that is not suitable for innovation.

What ***will*** potentially become a bottleneck is the rate of heat conduction out of the silicon die itself.  As power densities increase, you start to get limited not by the heatsink, but by your ability to get heat out of the CPU into anything at all, heatsink or otherwise.  There has been substantial innovation in this part, albeit still unused as its anticipated necessity proved incorrect.  This is something that occurs entirely in the CPU and does not involve the heatsink directly at all.  Things like incorporating micro heat pipes (more on those later!) into the silicon die itself.  But again, this will not impact heat sink design directly.

#### OK, but how *have* heatsinks/CPU coolers advanced?

They have advanced in every way that is possible.  They have gotten much lighter, use less material and certain types can be made very compact for their power dissipation, and finally their thermal conductivity, or specifically, heat flux capability.  Heat flux is the ability of something to move energy at a given rate per unit of area.  It is closely related to power density, the main difference being power density refers to heat generated per unit area, while heat flux is the amount of heat that moves through an area.

This is typically used in the context of conduction when it comes to CPU coolers.  Simply put, it is the heatsink's power density handling ability.  Thermal conductivity also effects every other aspect.  Thermal conductivity scales with cross section, so you need more material, with wider/thicker cross sections, to move more heat more quickly.  Even internally, it comes down to surface area effectively.

This stands in direct opposition to what we need to optimize for at the end of the cooling chain:  surface area.  Thicker fins mean we can fit less fins in a given volume, which means less surface area.  On the other hand, heat from the CPU below needs to actually move into the fins to be dissipated via convection.  It's a catch-22.

One that we have, to put it frankly, solved.

There are two materials that are known to be more thermally conductive than copper:  silver, which is only barely (it is 5% more thermally conductive than copper), and solid diamond.  Diamond is, for obvious reasons, not going to be practical and cannot practically achieve the shapes and thin section sizes needed anyway.

Copper is the best there is, at least for heatsinks.  But copper is no wonder material.  While it has higher thermal conductivity than just about anything (even aluminum is only 61% as thermally conductive as copper), that thermal conductivity is still not very fast.  If you hold a thick copper rod a foot long, and heat one end of it with a torch, it will take a surprisingly long time before you start to feel the heat on the other end.  Not even seconds, but a good fraction of a minute or more (obviously it will depend on the flame temperature, the size of the copper, and the length, but you get my point).

And the rate of heat flow just becomes that much less into fins as they get thinner.

With no better materials, this might seem like an insurmountable problem.

Enter heat pipes.  Heat pipes are so good that, if you play with one in your hands, doing the same torch experiment I described, they seem downright ***unphysical***.  With a quality heat pipe like the ones used in CPU coolers, if you heat one end with the torch, you will feel heat appear on the other end almost immediately.  A fraction of a second.

And that is because heat pipes can achieve thermal conductivities **that are hundreds of times higher than copper.**  Heat pipes are an order of magnitude (or two) more thermally conductive than ***any material in the known universe.***

And today, you likely can't find a CPU cooler without them.  Usually, more than one.  Thanks to this amazing thermal conductivity, heat pipes can achieve heat flux that is absolutely astonishing - \$23,000\frac{W}{cm^{3}}\$.  That is 4 times the heat flux out of the surface of our sun.

Give me a heat pipe large enough, and I will cool sun itself.  I will cool one that burns 4 times hotter than our sun.

This isn't even as much as an exaggeration as you might think - in places like Alaska, the permafrost is melting in some locations (which destabilizes the ground in the whole area, causing once solid ground to turn into a muddy, swamp-like mush, with anything built upon it sinking down into it).  However, this melting is being prevented via large heat pipes driven deep into the ground.  They cool the ground itself, and keep it solidly frozen.

Heat pipes have allowed the extremely thin fins on modern heatsinks.  Honestly, they are not even really heatsinks anymore - a heatsink is partly designed to have a high thermal capacity, which helps mitigate the relatively glacial speed that heat flows through just about everything that isn't a heat pipe.  Thanks to heat pipes though, modern 'heatsinks' are really just radiators - they need very little thermal capacity beyond a heat spreader near the CPU.  The heat pipes move the heat out very rapidly and into the fins to be radiated via convection, allowing modern heatsinks to cool much higher power densities with far less mass and somewhat reduced size.

In laptops, it allows the CPU (and GPU if present) to reside essentially anywhere inside the body, and a heat pipe or two is simply routed from the CPU to a small blower and copper fins at the side, allowing virtually all of the heat generated to be exhausted directly out the side as hot air, hugely improving how hot the body and other components of a laptop get.  There was a time when laptops would get so hot as to make your fingers sweat just from using the keyboard.  Those days are, thankfully, gone.  And that is a direct result of innovation that you think never even happened.

And innovation in this area continues to advance rapidly.  New cousins to heat pipes, such as vapor chambers which do for a 2 dimensional area what heat pipes do linearly have replaced heat spreaders in some cases.  Actual commercial products, like the Radeon VII, makes use of a vapor chamber to quickly spread the concentrated heat from the GPU die to a larger area, then into heat pipes.

There are many variations on this technology demonstrated and being commercialized - things like thermal diodes that allow heat flow in only one direction, or heat pipes with variable and controlled thermal conductivities, allowing very precise control of how heat will flow through them.

Simply put, the performance of a modern CPU cooler heatsink is many times that of older, no-heat pipe heat sinks, and they will continue to improve if or when it is needed.  Right now, heat sinks have achieved more than enough performance for our needs, the cost has been reduced substantially, and so they are good enough.  More innovations, at least in the consumer CPU cooling space, will occur if or when they are needed, and at the moment, they aren't.  But even when they are, I promise you that the hypersinks of the year 3030 will still fundamentally look like, well, heat sinks.  Surface area is king, and that is a solved problem.

#### But how?

A quick aside since you might be curious how heat pipes work their magic:  They are a hollow tube, usually with an extremely high surface area 'foam' of sintered material, usually copper with consumer heat pipes, lining the inner surface, but not extending all the way to the center.  Like this: [image]

That high surface area 'foam' is able to passively move a working fluid inside the heat pipe via capillary action.  This is the same effect that wicks wax from a candle up the wick to be burned, or allows a napkin to become entirely soaked just from a corner dipped in a glass of water.

The heat pipe is filled with a working fluid determined by the temperature range it is intended for, but the working fluid in CPU coolers is typically water.  It is only partially filled, and then a partial vacuum is pulled inside the heat pipe, and it is sealed with that partial vacuum maintained.  This substantially lowers the boiling point of the water/working fluid.

And now, a bit of heat at one end (or really anywhere) will begin to boil the working fluid, allowing the latent heat of the fluid to act as a heat absorber.  Just imagine how little water from a pot of boiling water is gone even after being boiled for an hour.  That is a ton of heat that the water absorbed, and it generated a quite unimpressive amount of steam.

Thanks to this high latent heat, this means that a little steam goes a long way.  And due to the sealed nature of the heat pipe, the steam will always move to the colder parts of the heat pipe, taking all that heat it absorbed with it.  It then will condense back into liquid, similar to rain clouds condensing out of the air, overburdened with humidity that it is no longer hot enough to contain.

The steam changes back to liquid, and is then wicked back to the less wet areas of the heat pipe.  These areas are, of course, the areas where the water is being removed and turning into steam.  The hot places.

This cycle continues, passively, as long as there is heat within the working range of the heat pipe.  There is no moving parts, and while not solid state, they are as good as.  They are extremely reliable and as long as they are not crushed or lose their seal, they will continue to do function.

Vapor chambers work on the same principle, but with the flow largely orthogonal, in a thin sandwich instead of a long tube.

Comment: Thank your for that truly mind expanding answer of breath and depth! I was really underestimating the roll of those pipes near some heatsinks. It was fascinating to read your the information you posted on the importance of energy efficiency in data center and the role of heatpipes in Alaska. Posters like you make StackExchange still one of the highest quality technical forums on the internet. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

My consumer level desktop computers mostly have pump/heat exchangers on the CPU with a separate radiator and a couple large fans mounted on the case, with fluid-filled tubes between.

My notebook computer has heat pipes running from certain chips to a heat exchanger and small fan.

The science of getting heat from a small area to the room air has not really changed in 20 or 200 years, but there have been a few incremental improvements that allow 50 to 200 W generated in a few square cm (a square inch or so) of area to be moved out to the room air without adding too much weight or volume.

In the 1960s we would probably have  used a kg or so of aluminum and a large fan or water cooling to get hundreds of watts out of a big hockey-puck thyristor.

Heat pipes have been around for more than 60 years, fans, radiators and electric pumps as well, but many of those things were too expensive for consumer use. Mass production and Asian manufacturing has led to (at one time unimaginably) cheap, light and good fans, pumps, heat pipes etc.

Comment: Heatpipes were quite exotic around 1980 when Sony used them to cool a stereo amplifier.

Comment: @BrianDrummond  I can remember seeing a commercial one (made by a California company) sometime in the 1970s. Aimed at military applications, of course.

Comment: Your PCs might be liquid cooled, but that's still prohibitively expensive for low-end or midrange computers. Though it's getting cheaper all the time.

Comment: @Hearth The price difference was maybe $30 or $50 USD between a good fan cooler (eg. Thermaltake Blue Orb) and a cheap closed-system liquid cooler. Cheap for the quietude, maybe $10/year.

Comment: Heat pipes, like other kinds of refrigerant based systems, rely on the heat given up to or input from the environment due to the phase change (from liquid->gas->liquid) of the working medium (refrigerant).  The latent heat of vaporization is much larger than the amount of heat that can be transferred merely by heating up, then cooling down the medium.  This is why steam is used to heat big buildings, because much more energy (heat) can be moved by converting the water to steam, moving the steam to the point of use, then allowing it to condense back into water.

Comment: Oh, and they are to go-to mechanism for moving heat in a space application.  Besides their efficiency, they are very reliable because there are no moving parts.